# Error: Invalid object "tbl_name"

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I am creating a small project by using winforms in C# using Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 - When I am creating setup and running it on the same computer it is working very well - but when I am running it on a different computer I got an error (Invalid object "tbl_name")! I'm using (SQL Server authentication) and my connection code is:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.DataSource = ".";
builder.InitialCatalog = "Sectors";
builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
builder.Password = "123";
builder.UserID = "MAK";
builder.AsynchronousProcessing = true;
builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
conn.Open();
```

Please help me find the cause of the error and resolve it.

Comment: What is the sql you are running against the connection?

Comment: Have you checked on your target server, if you can actually logon with your given credentials (or user if integrated security). And table is actually there in the database?

Comment: builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
and  builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
have opposite value but they are Synonym  and if you use windows authentication you must add target pc username in security of your database

Comment: remove builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true; and change builder.DataSource = "(local)"; and try again

Comment: I suspect the error message indicates you're talking to SQL Server OK (authentication succeeds) and the problem is with the statement.

Comment: still same erorr ,, i gave up Wallah :(

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the statement "builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;" and also try to change the connection settings (like DataSource to localhost).